# Read file based on pre-generated file name list?

Tags: c#, multithreading, file-io

If I know there will be, say 100 files, generated under my D:\ drive, and I know their name will be 001.tif, 002.tif, ..., 100.tif, how do I keep reading them until I read all the 100 files?
Files will be like this:
D:/001.tif
D:/002.tif
...
D:/100.tif

I would not think FileWatcherSystem, or something like that, is a good choice, because I don't have to worry about the file events in this case since these files are definitely going to be generated there. It is just a matter of time (very soon).
So I think I am gonna just need to read the hard drive (destination folder) indefinitely until all the files are read.
Any one has any opinion how I should do this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do the files already exist or do you want to process the files as they are copied/moved into the directory?

Comment: They do not yet exist, but they will. I don't know when, maybe in 10 milisecons, maybe in 100 miliseconds, maybe in 1 second. You are absolutely right, I want to process them once they are ready (copied/moved/generated).

Comment: Sounds like a job for FileSystemWatcher. What's wrong with using one?

Comment: I am going to plot the data real time, but the FileSystemWatcher misses events. So I think I should rely on the file name list that is generated in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically use a while(true) loop to watcher the folder; Once the file is ready, I read it, and process it. This procedure is done until all files are taken care of. Here is the code:

```
 public void ReadIndefinitely(string tiffFileFolder, List<string> channelName, int signalLength)
        {            
            string tiffFileName; 
            int nActiveStats = _signalDisplay.NActiveStatsOneChannel;
            int nActiveChannels = _signalDisplay.NActiveChannel;
            double signal;
            double DeltaT;
            bool keepReading = true;
            int channelIndex;
            int statIndex;
            int signalIndex = 0;

            while (signalIndex < signalLength)
            {                
                for (int i = 0; i < nActiveChannels; i++)
                {
                    tiffFileName = tiffFileFolder + channelName[i] + "_0001_0001_0001_" + (signalIndex + 1).ToString("0000") + ".tif";
                    channelIndex = (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(ChannelList), channelName[i]);
                    keepReading = true;
                    if(keepReading)
                    {
                        if (File.Exists(tiffFileName))
                        {
                            if (!IsFileLocked(tiffFileName))
                            {
                                for (int j = 0; j < nActiveStats; j++)
                                {
                                    statIndex = _statsEnableEnumIndex[j];
                                    DeltaT = ExtractTiffDeltaT(tiffFileName, "DeltaT=", 1);
                                    signal = _signalManager.GetSignal(statIndex, tiffFileName);
                                    UpdateSignal(channelIndex, j, signalIndex, DeltaT, signal);
                                }

                                keepReading = false;
                                signalIndex++;      
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                   // if (signalIndex % 5 == 0)
                    _signalDisplay.SetData(_XList, _YList, true);
                }


            }
        }
```

I have to warn you that this operation took my 90% CPU.